# How to match a string containing double quotes?

Tags: regex, scala

I want to match a string containing double quotes like this "ABC"DEF"" using Scala regex. Here's my pattern:

```
val pattern = "\"[^\"]*\"".r
```

The fact is I want to match some LOLCODE string (it doesn't use `\"` to present a quote inside a string, it use `:"` instead).

Please help me!

Comment: LOLCODE?  I just had to Google that.  Are you serious?  This is the most ridiculous language I've ever seen. :)  Anyway... if you are serious, and it uses `:"` for quotes in a string, wouldn't you just replace the `\"` with `:"` in your pattern?

Comment: I want to include `:\"` but exclude `\"`, and yes, LOLCODE is a madness to me, I don't even know why people create it lol...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work:

```
val pattern = "\"((:\")|([^\"]))*\"".r
```

(I haven't tested it)